# How can a desktop mail client be configured to read local mail?

Tags: linux, email, unix

This seems like something that should be doable, but I'm having no luck figuring it out and Google isn't helping much either.

Is there a way to use claws-mail (or another client) to view local mail (freebsd or linux) without the use of an smtp relay or anything?

It seems like I should be able to just point it to username@localhost or something and it would work, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I need to do.

Thanks

Comment: Install an imap server on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply "local mbox file" section at [Getting started with Claws Mail](http://www.claws-mail.org/manual/claws-mail-manual.html#ch_starting).